# Intelligent and thrifty HTML parsing (without downloading complete page source)?

Tags: android, html, html-parsing

I need to parse some webpage in my application, but I have 1 big problem - data. Page I want to parse has something between 400-500kb, depending on time. I need to parse it few times per day - depending on user request etc, but standard should be 10-20 times per day. However, I'm worried about data - if I parse it 10-20 times per day its 150-300mb in 1 month (10 x 30 x 0,5mb). Which is too much, as many people have 100mb limit. Or even 500mb limit, and I can't eat half of it with my app.

I need only very small part of web page data, is there a way to download for example only a part of web page source, or only some specific tags, or download it compressed, or any other kind of download whithout eating hundreds of mb per month?

Comment: Make a webservice that will parse for you, push updates to your app from your webservice (don't sync with website, sync with your service). That way you will waste data only if there were updates.

Comment: @Shark - that should be an answer.

Comment: this is not bad idea, but when I will have 1000 of users, and everybody will send 10 request per day on my webservice, and then webservice will parse data, it will be too much traffic (10000 request per day) from single IP address (my webservice) so it can be banned...Am I right? I don't have too much experiences with things like this...

Comment: @Alohci i didn't feel it had the necessary information required for an answer, it was more of a suggestion.
As for you qkx, your webservice will parse the webpage 20 times per day; your webservice will get hit by 1000s of users with thousands of request. Basically, your webservice will be your buffer - and update control - it will parse the data you need and forward it to users (apps) that wish to be updated. That way you waste data only on asking the server if it has updates and waste all 500kb if there is an update. So your app never deals with the parsed webpage, only your webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this would probably need some co-operation from the web-server, if you are downloading the page from a server that isn't under your control then this is probably not possible.

One thing to bear in mind is that modern web browsers and servers typically gzip text-based data, so the actual amount of data being transferred will be significantly less than the uncompressed size of the pages (to get a rough idea of how big the transfer will be, try using a zip utility to squash the raw HTML).

One further thing that might help is the [HTTP Range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35), which may or may not be supported by your server - this lets you request particular parts of a resource, specified by a byte range.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of doing it is to set up a proxy server, which will download the page periodically, and extract the data you need, exposing that to your app in a smaller, more suitable format.

You could for example use a command line tool like `wget` or `curl` on a linux server, then use a script (php/perl/python/ruby/bash) to parse the data, and re-format it. Then you would serve the content using a web server (apache/lighttpd).

Personally, I would do the whole thing in `node.js`, if you have the luxury of your own server to use for this task.

Comment: opera mini works pretty much in this way - the mobile browser sends all page requests to opera's server, who fetches the pages on your behalf, then compresses the images, and reformats for the mobile screen before delivering the smaller package to your phone.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm now thinking about. BUT if client would send request on my proxy, instead of official server, than my proxy should always have up to date data (which mean my proxy must parse remote site at least every 10-15 minutes) - and the main problem is, that they can block my proxy if it will parse their page so often. If not, the data would be unactual. But if every user goes from phone directly to that site (not my proxy) they wouldn't block him, because it will only send request few times per day...But user will waste a lot of data per month. Its lose-lose situation :)